# git un-remove before commit?

Tags: git

I accidentally did a

`git rm filename.txt -f`

now if I do a `git commit -m ''`, it will commit this delete.  How do I un-remove it before I do a git commit?

Comment: I certainly hope you're not in the habit of committing with empty messages...

Comment: It's embarrassing, but yes...i do tend to do that when i was using subversion.  But luckily, git commit by default asks me for a message

Comment: Yeah, my recommended practice would be to run just `git commit` (no arguments) and let it open the editor and nudge you along.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

To get the version from the current commit (`HEAD`) into both the index (staging area, what you're about to commit) and the work tree:

```
git checkout HEAD filename.txt
```

Note that this isn't just for "unremoval" - it's for getting you back to the version from the commit, whether you've modified it by changing one line or deleting the entire file.

Also, in case others find this looking for a slightly different answer, if you want to get the version from the *index* back into the work tree, you can use

```
git checkout filename.txt
```

That's handy for when you manage to stage everything for a commit, then do something stupid (like remove a file) - you can save yourself by recovering from the index.

Comment: +1 particularly for mentioning that this also stages the file - I think it causes confusion that (on S.O. anyway) people typically don't mention this when describing the effect of `git checkout <tree-ish> -- <path>`

Comment: @Mark: Ah, yes, that could catch you by surprise. It makes more sense if you think of the index as sitting between the work tree and the repository for all operations, not just work tree -> index -> commit.

Comment: Any tips on special characters? I try to never use them in filenames but in this case: `git checkout HEAD "...logo-construcci\303\263n.svg"` file with spanish accent is not found: `error: pathspec '...logo-construcci\303\263n.svg' did not match any file(s) known to git.` but git status shows: `deleted:    "...logo-construcci\303\263n.svg"`

Comment: @AlexandruTrandafirCatalin Try tab completion, or globbing, if there's no similar filenames to worry about (`...logo-construcci*n.svg`)?